# Invalid arguments Candidates Are: '....'

Tags: c++, hashtable

I have the following Hash Table Insert Function;

```
template<class T>
void Hash<T>::Insert(int key, const T& value) {

    int index = key % tableSize;
    HashNode<T> node(key, value);
    array[index]->insert(key,node);
    numOfElements++;
    // Check if need to rehash and do it
    Rehash();

}
```

and Im trying to use it within this code:

```
StatusType Department::AddMagi(int MagiID,int MagiLevel){
    if(MagiID <=0 || MagiLevel <=0) return INVALID_INPUT;
    Magi magiToInsert(MagiID,magiCount,MagiLevel);
    try{
        hash.Insert(MagiID,magiToInsert);
        magiRank.insert(magiCount,magiToInsert);
    }catch(Tree<int,HashNode<Magi> >::ElementAlreadyExists& e){
        return FAILURE;
    }catch(RankTree<int,Magi>::ElementAlreadyExists& e){
        return FAILURE;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Edit: this is the class Department:

```
class Department {
    int magiCount;
    Hash<Magi> hash;
    RankTree<int,Magi> magiRank;
    UnionFind creatureAreas;

public:
    Department(int n, int* Levels);
    StatusType AddMagi(int MagiID, int MagiLevel);
    StatusType RemoveMagizoologist(int MagiID);
    StatusType RemoveBarrier(int Creature1, int Creature2);
    StatusType AssignMagizoologistToCreature(int CreatureID);
    StatusType ReleaseMagizoologist(int MagiID);
    StatusType GetCreatureOfMagi(int MagiID, int* CreatureID) const;
    StatusType AreCreaturesInSameArea(int Creature1, int Creature2,
            bool* SameArea) const;
    StatusType GetSizeOfArea(int CreatureID, int* SizeOfArea) const;
};
```

Edit: a simple test case which works perfectly fine.

```
class Magi{
int id;
public:
    Magi(int id):id(id){}
    ~Magi(){}
    int getId() const{
        return this->id;
    }
    bool operator==(const Magi& magi){
        return this->id == magi.id;
    }
};

bool InsertTest(){
    bool returnValue = true;
    Magi m1(1);
    Hash<Magi> hash;
    hash.Insert(m1.getId(),m1);
    returnValue = (hash.Find(1) == m1);
    try{
        hash.Insert(m1.getId(),m1);
    }catch(Tree<int,HashNode<Magi> >::ElementAlreadyExists& e){
        returnValue = true;
    }
    Magi m2(12);
    hash.Insert(m2.getId(),m2);
    returnValue = (hash.Find(12) == m2);
    return returnValue;
}
```

at the hash.insert(...) im receiving this error:"Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void Insert(int, const Magi &)
'"
Ive tested that hash table multiple times on classes like this one and never got that error, what am I missing?

Comment: I don't see `magiCount` declared anywhere. Are you sure it's an `int`?

Comment: Error at hash.Insert or magiRank.insert ?

Comment: yeah the magiCount is an int whose a part of the Department class. The error is at hash.Insert as stated in the description..

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to discover the error without a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Could you just create a small simple program, which tries to insert that same type? It might also be helpful to post the complete traceback. I realise these can get long, but whatever is relevant would serve to narrow things down.

Comment: @tinstaafl The `Insert` function clearly takes a reference, and the error message indicates that too.

Comment: ive added a small example code for the Insert methd, as seen in the example code im not using reperance nor address in that test case..

Comment: Please post the entire message, including the types of the invalid arguments.

Comment: ive posted the intire message see last paragraph..

Comment: Please remove the irrelevant parts. There are 4 different insert in 2 different functions and it is not clear which insert fails. As others said: [mcve]!